# Having trouble importing nltk into Python3

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

When I run the command:

```
pip3 install nltk
```

My terminal outputs:

```
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (3.4.5)
```

But when I load up python3, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

This is driving me crazy, and I'm sure I'm missing something very basic, I just don't understand what!

Comment: first check if you have both Python 2.7 and 3.4. because pip was somehow installing nltk for one but not for the other.

Comment: Yup, that's it, I just used pip3 to download everything to Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out last week, but it requires moving the nltk package from the Python 2.7 library to the Python 3 library. If that's too difficult, another option is to delete the package in whatever location shows up and reinstall with
`pip3 install nltk`